# Why do bones without visible weights move the mesh?

Tags: weight-painting

I'm using Blender 2.82.

It looks to me as if the first 2 bones in my .blend file do not have any weight.

[image]

However rotating them cause my mesh to deform.

[image]

[image]

I know that rotating the root bone causes the mesh to rotate, but that is not what I mean. In fact, parts of the mesh are deforming.

Why is this happening, and how can I resolve this?

Rotating the first 2 bones should not have any effect.

I have also uploaded a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esw-DVc1T8M) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually blue doesn't necessarily mean zero weight. To make sure that a bone has zero influence you need to enable the *Zero Weight* option in the *Viewport Overlays* panel. The black areas mean real zero weight. Here you can see that the second bone has influence on a large part of your object.

I don't know why zero weight is not displayed by default in *Weight Paint* mode by the way, blue confuses people as they may think there's no influence when actually there might be.

[image]

Also note that you can make sure that a bone has no influence: select it and in the *Properties* panel > *Bone*, disable the *Deform* option.

[image]

The first bone's *Deform* option is deactivated but as it makes the others rotate, and as the others have influence on the top of the mesh, rotating the first bone will move the top of the mesh.

I guess you need to set your armature correctly, reparent the mesh to the armature, and give corrections in *Weight Paint* mode (most of the time parenting *With Automatic Weight* is not right away correct).

Comment: What do you mean by "set your armature correctly"?

Comment: I didn't mean yours was not set correctly, I meant make sure that it is  ;)  I don't know your project so I can't tell, for example, are you sure that your first bone must not deform?